# C# Mongo Aggegation for Minimum value

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get the minimum data for my collection and the following query works for me.   Now I am trying to add the Timestamp for this minimum value how can I do that?

```
public class Metric
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string TagName{ get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public decimal? Val { get; set; }

}

               var x2 = aggregate.Group(
                                x => x.TagName,
                                g => new
                                {
                                    MinVal = g.Select(
                                        x => x.Val
                                    ).Min()

                                }
                                )).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of aggregate, you would have to sort by Val, then pick the first item.

```
var item = aggregate.Sort(x => x.Val).First();
```

Then you can get item.Timestamp. If there could be overlap, and you need the min timestamp, you would have to sort by Val and Timestamp.